# Encyclopedia of American Quaker Genealogy volume 5 full text

Tags: pennsylvania, quakers

In looking at the full text for the "Encyclopedia of American Quaker Genealogy" available at https://catalog.hathitrust.org/Record/000859833 , it appears to be missing the full text for volume 5.

Is anyone aware of an online place where I can view the text of volume 5?

The index shows my names of interest on page 524 and 535.

Comment: It appears to be available on [Ancestry](https://www.ancestry.com/search/collections/3753/), but my subscription has expired, so I can't check the pages you need are available.

Comment: I checked Ancestry and both pages listed in the Q are there.  I have written a general answer about how to find the Encyclopedia (both offline and online) so the question and answer will be useful to the general public.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To avoid posting a one-line answer, I am going to address the general case of how to access volumes of Hinshaw's Enclyclopedia. They are **Limited - search only** status at Hathi Trust due to [copyright restricitons](https://www.hathitrust.org/help_copyright#RestrictedAccess).

First, some context for users who are unfamiliar with the Encylopedia. The  [LibGuide from Guilford College](https://library.guilford.edu/c.php?g=111831&p=958906) is worth bookmarking because it has information on how to access it online (as I write this, through Ancestry), and how to use it, including a list of abbreviations used.

The Encyclopedia is currently in print from Genealogical.com. They described the Enclylopedia in a recent blog post: [Pre-eminent Source for Quaker Ancestors](https://genealogical.com/2022/04/18/pre-eminent-source-for-quaker-ancestors/).

**Purchase options:**

Volumes of the Encyclopedia are available for purchase (print or ebook) via Genealogical.com's [store](https://genealogical.com/store/?gpc_search=1&woof_text=Encyclopedia%20of%20American%20Quaker%20Genealogy). The Master Index Volume is also available for purchase at [Family Roots Publishing](https://www.familyrootspublishing.com/store/product_view.php?id=2808&title=Index%20to%20Encyclopedia%20of%20American%20Quaker%20Genealogy). For used volumes, the meta-search engine [Bookfinder.com](https://www.bookfinder.com/) shows results from many different book-buying sites including ABEBooks, Biblio.com, eBay, alibris, Amazon, etc.

**Find in a Library:**

- Find a copy in a library near you by entering your zip code in [WorldCat](https://www.worldcat.org/title/encyclopedia-of-american-quaker-genealogy/oclc/733646). Many local genealogical and historical societies may also copies in their libraries; some list their holdings in WorldCat.
- The Encyclopedia is available for users who are [on site at the Family History Library in Salt Lake City](https://www.familysearch.org/search/catalog/192159?availability=Family%20History%20Library).

**By subscription:**

- As part of a [site-wide subscription](https://genealogical.com/book-bonanza-subscription/) to Genealogical.com.
- at Ancestry: [U.S., Encyclopedia of American Quaker Genealogy, Vol I–VI, 1607-1943](https://www.ancestry.com/search/collections/3753/)

**Other online options:**

Volume 1 is available to borrow from the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/).

Volume 7 (the later addendum from the Indiana Historical Society) can be searched via the genealogy book search site [GenealogyGophers](https://www.gengophers.com/#/titles?keywords=quaker%20encyclopedia&page=1).

If you don't have a subscription to Ancestry, see if your local library or genealogical society has access to Ancestry Library Edition. If your local library or society doesn't have copies of the Encyclopedia, you might be able to get copies of the individual pages by asking another library to make copies for you, such as the Genealogy Center at the Allen County Public Library, or the Family History Library in Salt Lake City.

**Negative Results:**

MyHeritage does have some Quaker resources in their collection, but as of the time of writing this answer, I did not see Hinshaw's Enclyclopedia in the [Collection Catalog](https://www.myheritage.com/research/catalog).